# What do the scriptures say about sexual life?

Tags: vedas, scripture, sex

Sex is necessary for continuing our generations. What do our scriptures say about sex? What do they say about steps to take for having healthy children and what things we have to do before, during and after sex for this purpose? Any procedure, activities, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Hindu samskaras cover an individual’s entire life span from conception to funeral rites. Hindus believe sexual intimacy between married couples is a sacred act.

**Sex life is especially meant for having good children**. The circumstances for creating good children are mentioned in **Kama-sastra of Vatsyaayana**, the scripture in which
 suitable guidelines are provided for a glorious sex life. Everything needed is mentioned in various scriptures. Kama Sutra   is an ancient   text widely considered to
 be the standard work on human sexual behavior in Sanskrit written by **Vatsyaayana**.  It includes a 
 section on practical advice on sexual intercourse.   **"Kaama**” which is one of the four **Purushaarthaas** or Human goals of life, means   sensual as well as sexual
 pleasure and "Sootra” literally means a thread.  Sootra means aphorism.    Kama sutra is not just an exclusive sex manual; it  presents itself as a guide to Grihastaasrama,
 family life to lead virtuous and gracious living .

Good sexual relations have been considered as a sacred responsibility in Hindu way of Life and have been ceremoniously observed offering prayers to their favorite
 gods and goddesses.  Before engaging in sexual intercourse, both the husband and the wife must consider their mental condition, the particular time, the husband’s direction, and  obedience to 
 the demigods.

According to the Vedic ritual called **Garbhadhana-samskara** is very important for generating good population. Our focus should not be to check the growth of the population,
 but to generate good population.The conditions for having good progeny in society are that the husband should be disciplined in religious and regulative principles and the
 wife should be  faithful to the husband. In Bhagavad-gita (7.11) it is said that sexual intercourse according to
 religious principles is a divine act.

> Sa ya ichchet putro me suklo jaayeta vedamanubraveeta
>   sarvam-aayuriyaaditi ksheerodanam paachayitvaa
>   sarpishmantam-asneeyataam-eeswarau janayitavyai         (6-4-14)

Sage Saunaka defines Garbhadana as “the rite by the performance of which a woman receives the rethas (semen) scattered by her husband called Garbhalambhanam or
 Garbadaanam.

> Nishekaad baijikam chaino gaarbhikam chapamrijyate |  kshetra
>   samaskaarasiddhischa garbaadaana phalam smritam ||

A well planned mating of the couple ensures a suitable conception that results in a capable child. 
 The negative qualities in the semen and the ovum become ineffective.  A good conception is the fruit of understanding and mutual planning.

> sa yaavaanha vai vaajapeyena yajamaanasya lokoe bhavati taavaanasya
>   lokoe bhavati ya evam vidwaanadhopahaasam charatyaasaam) streenaaam
>   sukritam vringkte atha   ya idamavidwanadhoepahaasam charatyasya
>   striyah sukritam  vrinjate || (6-4-3)

**If a person copulates conceiving it as a holy sacrifice,** he becomes the recipient of as much respect in the world as a man gets performing Vaajapayee fire 
 sacrifice. He gets all the good fortunes of those women. But if a person engages in   this copulation without thinking of it as a **holy sacrifice (Homa)** the women
 will take away all his merits.

> Sa yaam-icchchet-kaamyetam-eti | tasyaam-artham nishthaaya mukhena
>   mukha(m)-sadhaamyopastham-asyaa abhimrisya
>   japed-“angaad-angaat-sambhavaci hridayaad- adhijaayase  | sa
>   tvamangakashaayo asi digdhaviddhaamiva maadaye-maam-amoom mayeeti ||”
>   (6-49)

If the husband loves the wife and desires he gets into the mood of mating and recites the mantra:    “You are born from every one of our limbs and also sprung from our 
 intellect. You are the essence of our limbs. May this wife of mine be anointed with happiness! May she be happy with me!”
  Then in the act mating he recites the following mantra: “…..**Indriyena te retasaa reta aadhadaameeti garbhinyeva bhavati ||**
 ”  “By my strength and seed, I make you bear  your seed” and she verily becomes pregnant.  (6-4-11)
  [Sexual act description part in this mantra has not been included.]

> In   Sushruta Samhita 2/46/50 it is said:
>
> Aahaar-aachaara-cheshtaabhir-yaadrisobhih samanvitee |  Stree-pumso
>   samupeyaatam tayoh puthro-api  taadrisah ||

Depending on the diet, temperament and behavior, of the man and woman at the time of physica
 intimacy, the son born of such a union will   also have a similar temperament. (Sushruta is the famous ancient physician of Ayurveda)

> Sa ya ichchet putro me suklo jaayeta vedamanubraveeta
>   sarvam-aayuriyaaditi ksheerodanam paachayitvaa
>   sarpishmantam-asneeyataam-eeswarau janayitavyai         (6-4-14)

If one wishes to have a fair child, study  one Veda and attain full term of life; he and his wife should eat rice cooked in milk mixed with clarified butter. Then they 
 will succeed in their mission.

**Highly enlightened parent can train a child so that the child will not have to come back again to this miserable world. Parents should see to it
 that the child born of them does not enter the womb of a mother again.
 according to the Vedic ritual called Garbhadhana-samskara is very important for generating good population. Our focus should not be to check 
 the growth of the population, but to generate good population .**

Brihadaaranyaka Upanishad in its fourth section describes the **Putramanthana** mantra rites by which a house-holder can get a   worthy son or a worthy daughter.

Geetaa says in 7-11 **Dharmaviruddho bhooteshu kaamosmi**” –I am the lust (sexual desire)   in  all living beings  not conflicting with Dharma  for the sacred and sole
 purpose of creation.

**Lust with proper application is a virtue and not a sin**

Source-:  [Google books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iZ5RAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=Sex+life+is+especially+meant&source=bl&ots=PJIxkQuJaI&sig=itOvrROnYfChA3C847RVfB4y31Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyk_7cx83NAhVIqI8KHZUGB8gQ6AEIIjAE)

Comment: Where can I get shusrutha samhita online?

Comment: @Parikshitha - You can read it here -https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-1-sutrasthana as well as you can download it from here https://archive.org/details/englishtranslati00susruoft